# Which Mathematica function has the longest name (by character length?)

Tags: functions, symbols

I came across `DamerauLevenshteinDistance[u,v]` in the [documentation center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DamerauLevenshteinDistance.html?q=DamerauLevenshteinDistance) so that got me thinking:

Which documented Mathematica function has the longest name?

Also, is there is a limit to the length of a symbol name?

Comment: Let's see both -- with context, and without

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Which documented Mathematica function has the longest name

I assume then you want all of Mathematica, which includes all standard packages and contexts that come in the installation and not just in the `System` context.

I just run some code I have and added a check to obtain this information. Here is the table. According to this:

1. `ProtonProtonElasticCrossSectionAtCenterOfMassEnergy10GeV` at 56 in
   $\text{CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`*}$
2. `AddUsedToGenerateSideEffectGraphicsFunctions` in the `FrontEnd` with length 44.
3. `GenericCylindricalAlgebraicDecomposition` at 40 in
   `Experimental` context
4. `InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder` at 39 in `DifferentialEquations`
5. `CompileFunctionCallWithArithmeticFlags` at 38 in `Internal`
6. `MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution` at 38 in the `System`

Full table is below.

I put this table below in a PDF to make it easy to see (can zoom in PDF). The link is at this [page](http://12000.org/my_notes/compare_mathematica/V10/main.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I used Artes' code with ``"*`*"``.  New in V10.  Along with the one everyone has been yearning for, ``CalculateParse`Content`Calculate`AmusementParkRideData``.

Comment: @MichaelE2: `CalculateParse`Content`Calculate`AmusementParkRideData` If only I had known that had existed when I spent all those hours coding up [`TeacupsRide.nb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teacups).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just did not have "CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`" in my list of packages, since I could not find it on the installation disk. I just added it there. Will update now.

Answer (score 19):

```
Max[StringLength@Names["System`*"]]
```

> ```
> 38
> ```

```
 Select[ Names["System`*"], 38 == StringLength[#] &]
```

> ```
> {"MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution"}
> ```

As far as I can say there is no limit for lengths of symbol names, besides that of the memory limitation.

Comment: And then there's `"CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`ProtonProtonElasticCrossSectionAtCenterOfMassEnergy10GeV"`... +1

Comment: +1. Could also do (in V10) ``MaximalBy[Names["System`*"], StringLength]``, which is a bit simpler.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. However `NameQ` acting on "CalculateUnits..." yields false...

Comment: I corrected already. This is an artifact of escaping, one needs to use double backticks when there is a backtick inside, and I didn't pay attention at first.

Comment: Yes, Leonid is right. I forgot some back ticks...``"CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`ProtonProtonElasticCrossSectionAtCenterOfMassEnergy10GeV"``.

Comment: ...also known as `CUUCSPPECSACOME10`.

Comment: The votes on this one must be killing you inside... ;)

Comment: As it turns out we seem to have only 2 functions that are palindromes: `Level` and `Csc` :-)